Birdtray fails to start Thunderbird(Both RPM version and flatpak version) due to an uniknown error
I use Birdtray to minimize my Thunderbird to the system tray as I often receive and send emails. For the past few days, Birdtray has been behaving weirdly on my Fedora 40 KDE.
Whenever I click on the tray icon of Birdtray, a dialog box with an error pops up. It did start the Thunderbird instance but clicking on the tray icon does not minimize the Thunderbird instance. Here is the screenshot of the dialog box.

I am facing the same issue with the RPM version. Here is the other screenshot.

However, if I use this command /usr/bin/flatpak-spawn --host /usr/bin/thunderbird to run Thunderbird from the terminal, Thunderbird starts without any issues. This is true for both versions.
Here is the log output for Birdtray when it attempts to start Thunderbird.
2024-07-05 17:54:19 Birdtray version 1.11.4 started 
2024-07-05 17:54:19 Triggering the unread counter update 
2024-07-05 17:54:19 Window ID found: 0 
2024-07-05 17:54:19 Starting Thunderbird as '/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn --host /usr/bin/thunderbird' 
2024-07-05 17:54:20 Window ID found: 0 
2024-07-05 17:54:21 Window ID found: 0 
2024-07-05 17:54:22 Window ID found: 0 
2024-07-05 17:54:23 Window ID found: 0

Can anyone help me fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

run into the same problem and it bothered me to no end since even the tracking of messages didn't work. Long story short:
The problem for me was Wayland, because it actually did launch Thunderbird but didn't register that it was running. So I went to flatseal disabled in Thunderbird and Birdtray "X11 windowing System" and "Wayland windowing system" and just activated for both "Fallback to X11 windowing system". No problems since then whatsoever.
